# How to add <div></div> and name+size+delete appear in new div. javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used ajaxSubmit to upload file to linux server successfully. After upload file,  name+size+delete should be appear in my website.

For example, 1.jpg、2.jpg、3.jpg were uploaded to server, my submit website shoule be appeared like:

```
1.jpg 3k delete
2.jpg 4k delete
3.jpg 5k delete
```

Before upload files, My html structure is :

```
<td style="width:30%" id="impPic">
            <div class="btn">
            <span>addFile</span>
            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="mypic">
            </div>
            <div class="files"><b>...</b><span>...</span></div>
        </td>
```

After uploaded three files, I wanted html like:

```
<td style="width:30%" id="impPic">
            <div class="btn">
            <span>addFile</span>
            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="mypic">
            </div>
            <div class="files"><b>...</b><span>...</span></div>
            <div class="files"><b>...</b><span>...</span></div>
            <div class="files"><b>...</b><span>...</span></div>
        </td>
```

My files has fixed css style:

```
.files{height:10px; font-size:10px;line-height:22px; margin:10px 0}
```

Here is my ajaxSubmit code:

```
var divD=1;
$(function () {
var files = $(".files");
newDiv = "<div class='files'+divD+''><b class='dataname'>'+data.name+'('+data.size+'k)</b> <span class='delimg' name='+data.name+'('+data.size+'k)' rel='+data.pic+'>delete</span></div>";
    $("#fileupload").change(function(){
    $("#myupload").ajaxSubmit({
        dataType:  'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
        ......
        },
        uploadProgress: function() {
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(newDiv).insertAfter($('#impPic div:eq('+divD+')'));
            divD = divD + 1;
            $('.files').html("<b class='dataname' >"+data.name+"("+data.size+"k)</b> <span class='delimg' rel='"+data.pic+"'>delete</span>");           
        },
        error:function(xhr){
            ......
        }
    });
  });
 });
```

But unfortunately, it failed. I suppose files'+divD+'.html is wrong. Who can help me ?

Comment: `newDiv = "<div class='files'+divD+''>` is not concatenating correctly. Correct the quotes: `newDiv = "<div class='files"+divD+">`. There are more quoting errors on this line.

Comment: @Milk, sorry my div class=files is fixed. I had updated my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problem with your code...

First was the html string "`newDiv`" that you are trying to insert and the second is the invocation for `jQuery .html()` on an string literal object "`files'+divD+'`".

You are expecting the `newDiv` object to have a concatenated html string with the value of `divD` and the data came from the response but object `data` is undefined until the logic flows in the success callback.

and I believe the second problem would return a jquery `TypeError` problem, as you are trying to call the `.html() function` on a non `DOM - jQuery object` .

Update your code and try it this way:

```
newDiv = "";
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        newDiv = "<div class='files" + divD + "'><b class='dataname'>" + data.name + "(" + data.size + "k)</b><span class='delimg' name='" + data.name + data.size + "k' rel='" + data.pic + "'>delete</span></div>";
        $(newDiv).insertAfter($('#impPic div:eq(' + divD + ')'));
        divD = divD + 1;

        $(".files" + divD).html("<b class='dataname'>" + data.name + "(" + data.size + "k)</b><span class='delimg' rel='" + data.pic + "'>delete</span>");         
    },
   ...
```

**EDIT:**

You can update the html string and add an Id to have a unique selector on each of the element with `files` class and instead of the above selector, change the `class selector "."` to an `Id selector "#"`.

and your code will look like these...

```
newDiv = "<div id='files" + divD + "'class='files'"...
...
$("#files" + divD).html("<b class='dataname'>" + data.name + "(" + data.size + "k)</b><span class='delimg' rel='" + data.pic + "'>delete</span>");
```

If that doesn't suit your needs you can just leave the first example above and update your css selector to:

```
[class^='files'] instead of `.files`.
```

This will select all of the element with a class that begins with "files".

Comment: ,sorry my div class=files is fixed. I had updated my code.

Comment: @stack you are almost there .. you need to concatenate the int object `divD` on the selector just like in my example, unless you really like to append the `data` on all the element with the class `files`

Comment: ,.files1{height:10px; font-size:10px;line-height:22px; margin:10px 0}......files2{height:10px; font-size:10px;line-height:22px; margin:10px 0}......files3{height:10px; font-size:10px;line-height:22px; margin:10px 0}......files4{height:10px; font-size:10px;line-height:22px; margin:10px 0}......I do not want too many filesXX css, it is ugly.

Comment: For example, I have 10 files to be uploaded, 10 files class css should be defined.What about 20?

Comment: Think of a generic name for your styling class. On your case I can't think of a better class name other than `file`. I updated my answer check it :)

Comment: Wow, it work OK, Thankyou very much. I choose div id='files'. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

`files'+divD+'` is a string, and you try to call method `html` from string, which does not exist.

Try `$('.files' + divD).html('something');` or `files.find('.files' + divD).html('something');`

Comment: ,sorry my div class=files is fixed. I had updated my code